# How to check if an element is droppable, draggable or other 'ble'?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable, jquery-data

I've got a bunch of elements with jQuery. Some are draggable, some are droppable and some are both. How can I detect if an element is draggable or droppable?

Comment: Why can't you use the original selector used when instantiating `droppable` or `draggable`?

Comment: @zzzzBov, my conrol is loaded using AJAX, so I don't know what happened on the document.

Comment: please show some code. I have no idea what you're talking about. If you're sending some HTML via AJAX, then why does it matter whether the element is draggable or droppable?

Comment: @zzzzBov an example is very difficult to create. Basically, I have a page... my js is loaded (with ajax), it needs to find all draggables and droppables at that moment and post the number of elements back to the server for logging.

Comment: and *why* do you need to log the number of draggables and droppables?

Comment: Because every draggable and droppable represents a certain object. The page needs to start logging the state at certain moments (or when objects are in a certain state) to determine the performance of the user.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could also use jQuery `data()` like this..

```
if ($(elem).data('draggable')) {
        alert("yes");
}
else {
        alert("no");
}

if ($(elem).data('fooable')) {
        alert("yes");
}
else {
        alert("no");
}
```

See it here: [http://bootply.com/60153](http://www.bootply.com/60153)

Comment: just make sure you don't actually write if/else statements without braces!

Comment: So jQuery registers all their '~bles' in the `.data`?

Comment: Yes, jQuery uses data() for a lot of internal stuff - http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/ - The CSS class checking is also viable, I'm not sure which would be better in your case, or from a performance standpoint.

Comment: Seems like its now called 'uiDraggable'.

Comment: In jQuery 2.1.0 it is called 'ui-draggable'

Answer (score 15):

This works for me with JQuery 1.10.2

```
if ($("el").data('uiDraggable')){ //or uiDroppable
   alert("draggable")
} else {
   alert("not draggable")
}
```

Alternatively it is possible to invoke .data() method without argument

```
$("el").data()
```

That should print something like

> Object {**uiDraggable**: $.(anonymous function).(anonymous function)}

where you can see object properties.

Answer (score 7):

For draggable elements:

```
$(elem).is('.ui-draggable')
```

or you could `filter`, or just select `$('.ui-draggable');`.

For droppable, you would use `.ui-droppable`, resizable is `.ui-resizable`, selectable is `.ui-selectable` for the container although the items you select are `.ui-selectee`, sortable is `.ui-sortable` for the container.

Comment: What is better? Css class checking or checking in the `data`? And why?

Comment: That really depends on your implementation. It's very easy to remove a class, it's also easy to remove some data. I'm getting the feeling that this question is a symptom of using the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

I use Modernizr:

```
if (Modernizr.draganddrop) {
// use drag and drop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the classes added by jQuery.

```js
if ($(this).hasClass('ui-droppable')) {
  // Is Droppable
} else {
  // Nope
}
```